# Can't install angular cli 'lchown' not found

Tags: npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am trying to install angular cli on macOS Big Sur v11.6 and npm version 8.1.
This is the command I am using as given in Angular Official documentation

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

I am getting this error despite logging in as root

```
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lchown '/usr/local/bin/sentinelctl'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lchown '/usr/local/bin/sentinelctl'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'lchown',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/bin/sentinelctl'
npm ERR! }
```

It fails in system call lchown

When I tried to enter
`lchown` in the terminal, it says `Command not found`.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: try without sudo

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: @Aravin I don't exactly remember what I did. But it had something to do with node or nvm version. After changing, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall node and npm, installing node via homebrew.

https://github.com/akamai/edgeworkers-examples/issues/145